# Is there a way to trigger an apps script function on sending mail from Gmail compose window?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm trying to track specific emails sent from my Gmail compose window using apps script. How can we trigger an apps script function to get sender, recipient email addresses, subject and body of the mail, when an email is sent?

Using composeUI, I can get draftMetadata that includes toRecipients, bccRecipients and ccRecipients, but I have to get these only when the mail has already been sent. And not just these, I need to get subject and body of the email also.

```
    var track = false;
function composeUI(e) {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();

  var handleChange = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("selectionAction");

  var checkboxGroup = CardService.newSelectionInput()
    .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
    .setTitle("Track this email")
    .setFieldName("checkbox_field")
    .addItem("Track Email", "checked", track)
    .setOnChangeAction(handleChange);

  section.addWidget(checkboxGroup);
  card.addSection(section);

  return [card.build()]; 
}

function selectionAction(e) {
  if(e.formInput.checkbox_field == "checked"){
    track = true;
    var allMails = GmailApp.search('in:sent');
    var prev_count = allMails.length;
    var new_count = prev_count;

    while(prev_count == new_count){
      new_count = GmailApp.search('in:sent').length;
    }

    trackNewMail();

  }
}

function trackNewMail() {
  var allMails = GmailApp.search('in:sent');
  Logger.log(allMails[0].getId());
}
```

This gives me the threadId of the mail I want to track. But I still cannot get subject, body of the mail.

Comment: Using [search("in:sent")](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) will return an array of threads with outgoing mail. I don't believe there's a trigger available for the behavior, but a time trigger could check it often enough. You could save outgoing mails to a sheet if it's important you don't take the same action twice

Comment: @Altigraph I want to track only specific emails, only if a the track email flag is set true in composeUI. I have used composeUI to create a checkbox that shows if the mail has to be tracked. Is it still possible with the search("in:sent")?

Comment: Please update your post to show the composeUI code you're using currently. I'm not completely sure what you're referring to. If you can provide a sample of what an email would look like, that may also help. It may be trivial to detect the emails in question after they're sent, or to add a flag in a way that wouldn't be noticeable to the recipient

Comment: @Altigraph I've tried using the above code, allMails[0].getId() gives id of the most recent mail (which may not always be the one I have to track). And also, when I try using getFirstMessageSubject() instead of getId(), it does not return anything but when I run it (getFirstMessageSubject()) from the message inbox, it works well and returns mail subject.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the compose UI you're using, but as for the GmailApp bit, the search returns an array of GmailThread objects, [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) ; the Id you're referencing isn't for the 'mail', per se, but rather the thread object. `var mail = search()[0].getMessages()[0]; var subject = mail.getSubject(); var body = mail.getBody();` will work for instance

Comment: My initial thoughts for a way around if there is no way to trigger an event would be to apply a [Label](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) and use that to filter your results in Apps Script (and e.g., remove it when you have saved the information) (preferrable); or use a Form and then handle the results with SpreadsheetApp and GmailApp as appropriate; or to hide something in the email (perhaps using htmlBody and a `display:none` div) which you could then check; e.g. looping through the results of `search()` if that doesn't work

Comment: What is it you're hoping to achieve with this? There's no way to track what happens to a mail from the sender's end, not to send information to a GMail Addon from the 'send' button in the compose window.